# d3 tool-tip calling on svg attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, tooltip

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a tool tip on each svg with their "text" attribute popping up. I'm using https://github.com/VACLab/d3-tip tool tip api. Is there a way to call an svg's attribute by function?

```
  <html lang="en">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 50);

  var d3tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3tip')
  .html(function(d){
    return d.text;
  });

  svg.call(d3tip);

  svg.append("g")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 10)
  .attr("cy", 10)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("text", "hi")
  .on('mouseover', d3tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', d3tip.hide);


  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I would like this code to have an svg on the screen, and as someone hovers over that shape, it would pop up its "text" attribute which is "hi" for now.
But this code is telling me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined. How should I fix this?

Comment: Hi. Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: It appears as though you are using jquery, but the question is not tagged with jquery. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes I fixed it!

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yes, sorry I revised the example.

Comment: @AnnieLee I appreciate it. But did you click the link that Paul commented? You should read that. Your question does not have a Minimal, Complete, or Verifiable example.

Comment: S.O. has a code snippets feature which lets you embed runnable code in your question.  [See this page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Could you see if this works?

Comment: @AnnieLee I don't have a testing environment for this type of question, nor am I very good with javascript/jquery.